# When "dev-master" should be used in composer.json?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm starting to use Symfony2 and following many tutorials. I found that when they installed some new features using `composer.json`, they "always" declared `dev-master`. I don't know the reasons why they always use it. An example from [DoctrineFixturesBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html):

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Actually, I have googled and found some people written that:

- Given we use the `dev-master` instead of any *stable version*
- It could lead to some conflicts in the (intrinsic) future because the version today maybe `1.5.0` and tomorrow maybe `1.6.0`

So, what we really use in practical works? The `dev-master` or *specified, concrete version* and why?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**You should use a specific ( tagged stable at best ) version wherever possible.**

While `composer.lock` does lock the dependency to a specific commit even when using `dev-master` ... every `composer update` will update the dependency to the latest version and afterwards update the lockfile.

If your lockfile somehow gets deleted/lost and it is not backuped / under version control you can easily end up with a non-working project after running `composer install` or `composer update`!

A simple example would be `symfony/symfony` itself ... new commits might introduce new BC (backward compatibility) breaks in the `dev-master` branch any time leaving your application in a non-functional state.

Comment: "If your lockfile somehow gets deleted/lost and it is not backuped" - that's a pretty big "If". Also, clearly if this is the case, then that is the problem, not that you are using "dev-master". If your lock file can go missing then so can any of the other files, including the composer.json.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you specify "dev-master" as the version for a package in your composer.json file, Composer will clone the Git repository for that package and install the latest commit on the "master" branch. This can be useful when you want to test bleeding-edge features or contribute to the development of a package.

However, it's important to note that using "dev-master" can be risky because development branches are subject to changes, including breaking changes or unstable code. It's generally recommended to use specific tagged releases or stable versions of packages in production environments to ensure stability and avoid potential compatibility issues.

2. If you use `dev-master` with the repositories key in your composer.json file, it means you are specifying a custom repository from which Composer should fetch the package. The custom repository can be a Git repository, a path to a local directory, or a Composer repository (such as Packagist).

Here's an example of how you can include the repositories key in your composer.json file to use a custom repository with the `dev-master` version constraint:

```
{
  "repositories": [
      {
          "type": "vcs",
          "url": "https://github.com/vendor/package.git"
      }
  ],
  "require": {
      "vendor/package": "dev-master"
  }
}
```